# Load Spacy Wordnet Model From S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, spacy

I need to load a spacy model with more than 600MB to AWS Lambda, but I just found by downloading the model from S3 to /tmp, but it is larger than allowed (512MB), so an error occurs.

I also tried to use EFS and it worked, but the value was very expensive because it was necessary to configure NAT gateway.

Is it possible to load the model directly from the S3?

I have another idea that can work, which is using container no lambda, but first I would like to know if it is possible to do it with S3.

Comment: Your file on S3 is just a collection of bytes with a name. Instead of writing those bytes to a _file_ on disk, you could also write those bytes into a _variable_. Then the bytes would not be on disk, but in memory. In this case you need to make sure that your Lambda has enough memory (for example: 700MB). Furthermore, you should do this during initialisation, so that this happens just once.

Comment: Not directly from S3, build, I think we added some kind of wrapper function to load pickle model from S3, but, as of now I am not sure if some libraries can directly use S3 to load model or any other file for that matter without downloading it.

Comment: @Jens It is not just 1 file, it is a directory with several files. Is it still possible to load into memory? Or in that case it would be better to have the .zip file and unzip it to memory?

Comment: @GleidsonHenrique it is still possible, but to be honest: I would seriously rethink if Lambda is the right tool for the job. Since you did not provide any information what the end goal is, it is hard to tell though. But it feels "hacky". AWS offers a lot of services around ML, maybe they are better suited.

Comment: I agree with @Jens - I would rethink about the approach here. See, the problem is not loading it into the memory, now you have 10 GB of memory available, but, it's kind of hacky, it will increase complexity overall.